# No answer from a curl request

Tags: php, curl

Trying to curl this site but no output. Why is this not working?

```
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.paribu.com/ticker");  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks everybody

Comment: Here it is working as expected.

Comment: watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rd8SU7qzOZ0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would it output? Your not doing anything with the response :/

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.paribu.com/ticker");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 

// enable curl error reporting
$result = null;
if ($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
} else {
    // all good, decode the response
    $result = json_decode($output);
}

// Close the handle
curl_close($ch);

// echo something from it
if (isset($result->BTC_TL->last)) {
    echo $result->BTC_TL->last;
}
```

If it still does not work or throws errors, enable PHP error reporting.

Comment: Find the solution! it is a shared hosting so when I switch to a new panel (higher PHP version) the problem is solved.